Google Speech to Text Medical Model returning punctuation while enable_automatic_punctuation=False
I'm using google speech to text streaming to transcribe incoming audio. Our users will dictate punctuation, so another layer of default punctuation complicates the UX. The docs indicate that while enable_automatic_punctuation defaults to True for the medical model, it can still be set to false. However when I configure this flag to false, punctuation still appears in the transcription (usually during a pause in speech).
Here is my configuration
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=GoogleSpeechWrapper.encoding_map[client.audio_config["encoding"]],
            sample_rate_hertz=client.audio_config["sampleRateHertz"],
            language_code=client.audio_config["languageCode"],
            model=client.audio_config["model"],
            enable_automatic_punctuation=False,
        )
        streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config, interim_results=client.general_config["interimResults"]
        )

Is this a bug? Or is there something I'm misinterpreting with the enable_automatic_punctuation flag?
